# where do i put the "environment: " line to deploy to an environment in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've looked at the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops and set up an environment called test. However when I put this `environment: test` line in the below pipeline I get an error "unexpected value". Where do I need to put the `environment: test` ?

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:

- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - template: templates/build.yml

- stage: Release
  condition: and(succeeded('Build'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:
  - job: DeployDev
    environment: test
    variables:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ordinary job into a [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) :

```
  jobs:
    - deployment: DeployDev
      environment: test
```

Comment: i get error regarding steps ? Unexpected value 'steps'                                                                                                       - stage: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployEnv
    environment: test
    steps:
    - template: templates/build.yml

Comment: That's because a deployment job needs further settings, before the list of steps. See the link in my answer for full details.